# How do I fill the width of the screen with my toolbar using an Android GridLayout?

Tags: android, include, toolbar, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to fill the width of the screen UI with my toolbar, in a GridLayout.
The output I get is shown below.  Somehow the toolbar is getting truncated, please advise.

[image]

Below is code from my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    tools:context=".CardViewActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_columnSpan="4"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" >
</include>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/createSkycard"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Create a skycard"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
...
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just use a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as a parent and nest the 'GridLayout` in it with the `Toolbar` right before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is better if you use LinearLayout as a root, like following :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_columnSpan="4"
       layout="@layout/toolbar" >
   </include>

   <GridLayout
       android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:columnCount="4"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:useDefaultMargins="true"
       tools:context=".CardViewActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createSkycard"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_columnSpan="3"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:text="Create a skycard"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That did the trick for the toolbar.  I have some minor formatting issues but the toolbar width is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Your GridLayout has android:layout_width="wrap_content"
change it to "match_parent".